# Unresolved template argument

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

i was testing some template codes today and, i find out something interesting but I could not find any good reason to explain why does it happen. I request to you consider and enlighten me with your knowledge. Thanks for your time.

This code block is working without problem.

```
template<class TItem>
class PrintableQueue : public queue<TItem> {
    public:
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const PrintableQueue<TItem>& queue) {
            copy(queue.c.begin(), queue.c.end(), ostream_iterator<TItem>(os, " "));
            return os;
        }
};
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
    PrintableQueue<int> queue;
    queue.push(1);
    queue.push(2);

    cout << queue;
}
```

However, when i put the definition of friend function to the outside of the class, it does not work.

```
template<class TItem>
class PrintableQueue : public queue<TItem> {
    public:
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const PrintableQueue<TItem>& queue);
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const PrintableQueue<TItem>& queue) {
    copy(queue.c.begin(), queue.c.end(), ostream_iterator<TItem>(os, " "));
    return os;
}
```

The errors i got is below.

```
'TItem' : undeclared identifier
'PrintableQueue' : 'TItem' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'TItem'
```

My question is, why compiler can not resolve TItem ?

Comment: `TItem` is in scope for the class definition. You moved it out of the class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the function a function template.

First change the decleration of the operator<< in the class and include TItem into its signature

```
friend ostream& operator<< <TItem>(ostream& os, const PrintableQueue<TItem>& queue);
```

Than change your function definition to template function

```
template <typename TItem>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const PrintableQueue<TItem>& queue) {
    copy(queue.c.begin(), queue.c.end(), ostream_iterator<TItem>(os, " "));
    return os;
}
```

Comment: The error i got; error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Printa
bleQueue<int> const &)" (??6@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AEAV01@AEBV?$PrintableQueue@H@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl app3_queue(void)" (?app3_queue@@YAXXZ)
2>D:\workspace\tcppv2\4.container.others\build\Release\run.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: @MuratKarakuş, `ostream_iterator<TItem>` works only if you have the `operator<<` defined between `std::ostream` and `TItem`. You need to provide an implementation of that overload.

Comment: @Sahu i didn't understand your previous comment but i resolved it by updating function signature. Previously, i forgot to update function signature hence, it caused above error. Thank you for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't know what `TItem` is, it is now moved outside the class template.